# c# repository ICollection navigation error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am stuck and need help.
Checking user permission in a controller methods as below

```
                    if (User.IsInRole("CanAccessOnlyOwnDepartmentRequest"))
                    {
                        //CanAccessOnlyOwnDepartmentRequest yetkisinie sahipse
                        itemResult = await Repository.PaginatedListDescAsync(p => p.BranchAsset.BranchId == userBranchId &&
                            (p.AssigningUser.Employee.DepartmentId == branchUser.DataResult.Employee.DepartmentId ||
                                p.AssignedUser.Employee.DepartmentId == branchUser.DataResult.Employee.DepartmentId) &&
                            (p.Assignments.LastOrDefault().AssignUser.Employee.DepartmentId == branchUser.DataResult.Employee.DepartmentId),
                            p => p.Id, paging.PageIndex, paging.PageSize,GetNavigation:true);
                    }
```

what I am trying to do is that I want to check Request -> Assignments collections last item's assign user and assigned user Department ID whether is equal to the user who requested the result.

this is my request entity definitions of Assessments part

```
    private ICollection<RequestAssignment> _assignments;
    public virtual ICollection<RequestAssignment> Assignments
    {
        get => LazyLoader?.Load(this, ref _assignments);
        set => _assignments = value;
    }
```

I am using EF Core 2.1 and LazyLoading on the necessary entity property

the error I am facing:

**Property 'System.Guid DepartmentId' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[Q.Entity.Corporate.EmployeeEntity.Employee]'
Parameter name: property**

***EDİT :***
Request Class

```
    public Guid? BranchAssetId { get; set; }
    public BranchAsset BranchAsset { get; set; }

    public Guid AssigningUserId { get; set; }
    public BranchUser AssigningUser { get; set; }

    public Guid AssignedUserId { get; set; }
    public BranchUser AssignedUser { get; set; }

    public Guid StateTypeId { get; set; }
    public RequestStateType StateType { get; set; }

    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestFeedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestState> States { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestProcess> Process { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestMessage> Messages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestAssignment> Assignments { get; set; }
```

RequestAssignment Class :

```
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }

    public Guid AssignUserId { get; set; }
    public BranchUser AssignUser{ get; set; }

    public Guid AssignedUserId { get; set; }
    public BranchUser AssignedUser{ get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
```

BranchUser Class:

```
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee{ get; set; }

    public Guid BranchId { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }

    public Guid? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BranchUserRequestApproval> RequestApprovals { get; set; }
```

Employee Class

```
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public Person PersonInformation { get; set; }

    public Guid BranchId { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
```

Comment: One `Employee` property is a collection, not a reference. Another thing: you shouldn't call the `LazyLoader` like that. Just make `Assignments` an auto property and EF will do the rest.

Comment: this is my Employee property. not a collection.

        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

        private Employee _employee;

        public Employee Employee

        {
            get => LazyLoader?.Load(this, ref _employee);
            set => _employee = value;
        }

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to handle this?

Comment: We only see some random code fragments. You better show comprehensive code. Like, what is `branchUser.DataResult`? But first remove these `LazyLoader` calls.

Comment: var branchUser = await BranchUserRepository.GetSingle(userId);
return branch user information also have the related employee departmen id
I removed the LazyLoader

Comment: BranchUser.DataResult return below 
`Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee{ get; set; }

        public Guid BranchId { get; set; }
        public Branch Branch { get; set; }

        public Guid? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }`

Comment: Please edit your question. And show full classes. Or do a simple check: one of the things you try to get `.DepartmentId` from is a collection. It's really not that hard.

Comment: @GertArnold I have edited. You can see all class related to Repository.PaginatedListDescAsync methods.

Comment: Still not the code that gives rise to the issue. Again, check where you access `DepartmentId`. Somewhere you try to get it from a `IAsyncEnumerable`. Only you can figure that out. We don't have your code and we can debug it even less.